# Sorting ElasricSearch based on size of array type field

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch cluster on which I have to perform a sort query based on the size of the object array field 'contents'.

So far I have tried,

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "fields" : ['name'],
    "query": {
        "match_all": {} 
    },
    "sort" : {
        "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['contents'].values.length",
        "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

The above query gives me SearchPhaseExecutionException. The ES query is made from client side using elasticsearch.angular.js.

Any kind of help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

The security has changed for scripts in versions 1.2.x. In `ES_HOME/config/scripts` create a file called `script_score.mvel` and add the script:

```
doc.containsKey('content') == false ? 0 : doc['content'].values.size()
```

Restart Elasticsearch and change your query to:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "script": "script_score",
            "order": "desc",
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

For more information take a look here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/scripting-security/

Comment: Getting same exception SearchPhaseExecutionException after the change

Comment: What version of ElasticSearch are you using?

Comment: Tried the edit and I am getting following error
No field found for [contents] in mapping with types [clustername]

Comment: Can you post your mapping?

Comment: my mapping for the cluster does have the attribute I have checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59108/discussion-between-dan-tuffery-and-nikhilesh).

Comment: Use containsKey to to the null check, see my example.